# How to fix NSInternalInconsistencyException in Swift programming

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a new app, and I want to put in a hidden folder. Which is accessed by Face ID/Touch ID. I have implemented the code, but when I run the app, and use Face ID. The app crashes with the error 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.
```

In my Viewcontroller, I have set up the view as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let cornerRadius : CGFloat = 10.0
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    tableView.clipsToBounds = true
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0


    // 1
    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    // 2
    // check if Touch ID is available
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        // 3
        let reason = "Authenticate with Biometrics"
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason, reply: {(success, error) in
            // 4
            if success {
                self.showAlertController("Biometrics Authentication Succeeded")
            } else {
                self.showAlertController("Biometrics Authentication Failed")
                }
           })
     }
     // 5
     else {
         showAlertController("Biometrics not available")
    }
}
```

I want Face ID/Touch ID to work as expected and not crash if verified.

Comment: Your indentation is very confusing. Could you please properly format your code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are making UI call (Show alert) on background thread and therefore you are getting this issue.

Change the following

```
if success {
    self.showAlertController("Biometrics Authentication Succeeded")
} else {
    self.showAlertController("Biometrics Authentication Failed")
}
```

to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if success {
        self.showAlertController("Biometrics Authentication Succeeded")
    } else {
        self.showAlertController("Biometrics Authentication Failed")
    }
}
```

> if you gonna update the UI
>   part, remember always use DispatchQueue.main.async to run those tasks.
>   The UI Changes must run in main thread.

[How to add FaceID/TouchID using Swift 4](https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/how-to-add-faceid-touchid-using-swift-4-a220db360bf4)

You can also have look at [Logging a User into Your App with Face ID or Touch ID - Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id) If you scroll down to `Evaluate a Policy` Section.

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer worked, I will have a look at the documentation, again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear:

> Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.

You can't edit the UI from any thread besides the main thread, as you were attempting to do with your `evaluatePolicy` callback. You should put your UI modifying code within a call to `DispatchQueue.main.sync`